# How to select first component and calculate percentage of variation in PCA?

Tags: matlab, pca

I have a matrix M where the columns are data points and the rows are features. Now I want to do PCA and select only the first component which has highest variance.

I know that I can do it in Matlab with [coeff,score,latent] = pca(M'). First I think I have to transpose matrix M.

How can I select now the first component? I'm not sure about the three different output matrices.

Second, I also want to calculate the percentage of variance explained for each component. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you should transpose your input to have rows as data points and columns as features:

```
[coeff, score, latent, ~, explained] = pca(M');
```

The principal components are given by the columns of `coeff` in order of descending variance, so the first column holds the most important component. The variances for each component are given in `latent`, and the percentage of total variance explained is given in `explained`.

```
firstCompCoeff = coeff(:,1);
firstCompVar = latent(1);
```

For more information: [`pca` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html).

Note that the `pca` function requires the Statistics Toolbox. If you don't have it, you can either search the internet for an alternative or implement it yourself using [`svd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Let's say we have M=rand(100,30), i.e. we have 30 data points and 100 features. If I now do PCA, coeff is of dimension 100 x 29. If I take the first component I have still 100 features. How can I reduce the features?

Comment: I'm assuming you are again transposing so that you get 30 rows (data points) and 100 columns (features). `coeff` should be 100x100 (a square matrix of the number of features).

Comment: Your new, reduced features are the linear combinations of the original features with the computed coefficients. So, for example, if you want to keep only the most dominant feature, you would take `firstCompCoeff` from above. Suppose you now have 10 new data points `Mnew = rand(10,100);`, you would now get the reduced feature from them using `Mnew_reduced = Mnew * firstCompCoeff;`.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix has dimensions m x n, where m is cases and n is variables:

```
% First you might want to normalize the matrix...
M = normalize(M);

% means very close to zero
round(mean(M),10)

% standard deviations all one
round(std(M),10)

% Perform a singular value decomposition of the matrix 
[U,S,V] = svd(M);

% First Principal Component is the first column of V
V(:,1)

% Calculate percentage of variation
(var(S) / sum(var(S))) * 100
```